# Getting unknown empty property after joining relation in search model Yii2

Tags: php, sql, join, yii2

I added

```
$query->joinWith('projectParticipants');
```

in search model but got this error:

[image: Empty property]

relation is correct and returns data if I var_dump in view.

Tried as well

```
->leftJoin('project_participants', 'project_participants.user_id = user_cards.id')
```

but the same error. :(

With different relations the same problem and in Yii Debugger all queries are correct.

Where I could go wrong?
What is this empty property?

In model relation looks:

```
public function getProjectParticipants()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProjectParticipants::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}
```

**UPDATED**

```
public function search($params)
{

    $query = UserCards::find();

    $query->joinWith('projectParticipants');

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => array('pageSize' => 45),
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'project_participants.proj_id' => $this->projects,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['ilike', 'name', $this->fullName ])->orFilterWhere(['like', 'surname', $this->fullName ]);


    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Comment: Does this has anything with `jQuery`?

Comment: i think you didn't close a braket somewhere

Comment: @Tushar sorry, I wanted `query` not `jQuery`

Comment: @madalinivascu when I comment out this join line, then there is no errors.

Comment: Looks correct for me. Can you add code how `$query` is formed?

Comment: @arogachev added whole search function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with primary key - *user_cards* model was generated from db view where is no pk.

So the solution was to add

```
public static function primaryKey(){
    return array('id');
}
```

in model.